# Good way to present long questionnaires in methods?

Tags: writing, methodology, tables

I'm writing a paper (my first one) in a standard article form. I must use A4 pages and a single text column.

In Methods and Materials, I must present a 23-Likert item long questionnaire that was used in the research. The problem is, I can't find a way to fit all 23 items in a concise table or image, it always ends up as a behemoth that takes up 2 pages and doesn't really fit in.

Is there a better, concise way to present said questionnaire?

Comment: Did you already present this questionnaire to the audience (that will be answering it) in some other form?

Comment: @AntonMenshov Yes, I already have the distribution data plotted in a horizontal bar chart.

Comment: No, I mean, how did you present this questionnaire while you were collecting data?

Comment: @AntonMenshov It was done through Google Forms.

Comment: Why should the entire questionnaire be reproduced at all? Just describe it in an abstract manner. What is it about, what scales do you use, how is it administered, how did you work around error/bias, what's your response rate, these kinds of things...

Comment: @henning That could be a good option, since I'm going to present each item in the result charts anyway... But doesn't this make the methods a bit vague? Is it fine to prompt the reader to view the questionnaire items in the results section?

Comment: Does 'padronized' mean 'standard' here? Can you add supplemental material to the paper?

Comment: @Eduardo Cola have a look at how published research papers (journal articles) describe their survey methods. If the survey has more than three items, nobody describes the individual items in any detail. Instead, the full survey is sometimes available as an online appendix, if at all.

Comment: @Anyon sounds like a Portuguese malapropism of standardized.

Comment: In any case, if this is an assignment for a class, it's best to ask your instructor what the expectations are.

Comment: @Anyon Yes, sorry, will edit.

Comment: @Anyon I can't add supplemental material to this particular paper, that's why I was looking for ways to better present the methods.

Comment: @henning I will probably overall skip it, since the items are presented in the results anyway. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Twenty-three items isn't *that* long

Answer (score 4):

As I mentioned in the comments, 23 items isn't *that* many, unless the items are very long.

Here is how [Hurley et al. (2006)](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17146701/) introduces the 35-item Broad Autism Phenotype Questionnaire (it continues onto the next page):

[image]

As you can see, it is typeset smaller in a sort of table. I am not sure why they repeated the scale `1 2 3 4 5 6` on each row, as it is identical for each item.  Since you are limited to one text column, put 12 items on the left and 11 on the right.

At the bottom of the table, the asterisks are explained:

> ***Casual interaction with acquaintances, rather than special
> relationships such as with close friends and family members

Comment: The questionnaire must be published in order for the results to be credible. The table is a good example. I have used an Appendix.